# how do I unmount my phone

Tags: external-hdd, sd-card, usb-drive, smartphone

I am confused .  Do I need to mount a new sd card or phone or usb stick or external hdd drive every time I plug it in? And I cannot see them if I accidentally close them. I do not know how to eject them.  I am forced to just unplug

Answer (score 0):

mount it as a usb device.just plug it in to a usb port. it should show up in your home folder on the left as a external device. you can check it's status in terminal.if you want to eject it, then press the eject button near the icon or letters.